# python - Search for the max of a list recursively

Tags: python, recursion

Can Anyone please tell me why this code is returning `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`:

```py
def maximum(tab, indDeb, indFin):
    if (indDeb == indFin):
        return indDeb
    else:
        m = (indDeb + indFin) / 2
        print "m = ", m
        k1 = maximum(tab, indDeb, indFin)
        k2 = maximum(tab, m+1, indFin)
        if (tab[k1] > tab[k2]):
            return k1
        else:
            return k2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    maximum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, 4)
```

Comment: it appears the maximum recursion depth has been exceeded ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within `maximum` you are calling the function recursively without altering the arguments:

```
def maximum(tab, indDeb, indFin):
    # ...

    k1 = maximum(tab, indDeb, indFin)
```

This cannot but lead to infinite recursion.

Perhaps you wanted to limit the upper index instead:

```
k1 = maximum(tab, indDeb, m)
```

Comment: Yes! that was what was throwing the `maximum recursion depth error`.

Answer (score 5):

The line:

```
k1 = maximum(tab, indDeb, indFin)
```

should be:

```
k1 = maximum(tab, indDeb, m)
```